# Get image path selected from the gallery

Tags: java, android

I need to pass proper image (which I selected from the gallery) path to ExifInterface, but I cant seem to get it working...

```
 File myFile = new File(selectedImageUri.getPath());
 String patch = myFile.getPath();
```

This will return:

```
/document/image:489
```

I am trying to detect if the image is rotaded or not, but without this full path i.e. ../images/test.jpg it will not work. How do I get the proper image path??

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the proper image path?

For what feels like the 3,734<sup>th</sup> time, **there is no file path**.

Use [the `ExifInterface` from the Android Support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html). It offers a constructor that takes an `InputStream`. You can get an `InputStream` for the `Uri` by calling `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`.